# Call a recursive "method of a class" from a different "method of the same class"

Tags: php, class, function, methods

I asked [this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188518/recursive-function-in-a-php-class), and someone put a link to explain me **what a recursive function is**. *He/She* voted negative and so on, like in a **real recursive function**, all others voted me negative too.

Now I am **asking again**, how should I call a recursive *"method of a class"* from a different *"method of the same class"*? While doing the recursion IN the definition of the first "recursive method", should I use `$this->method()` or just `method()`

Thanks ;) *(I call it method of a class to avoid those who kill with negatives for saying "function")*

Comment: Calling a method recursively is no different than calling another method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call a method recursively the same way that you'd call any other method -- it's just that you're calling the method within itself.

For example, look at the following:

```
class A
{

  public function b($i = 0)
  {

    echo ++$i;

    if ($i < 10)
    {
      $this->b($i);
    }

  }

}

$a = new A;

$a->b();
```

This will print out the numbers 1 to 10 and then stop.

If you want to be clever, rather than use `$this->b($i);` you can use `$this->{__FUNCTION__}($i);`. Then, if you wish to rename the method at some point (or copy the method content elsewhere), you won't have to search for and rename each recursive call.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the example. My doubt came because my script stops when calling the recursive function... so it has to be a different issue ;)

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the method along with the actual input values you're giving it. I noticed there were `return`s before the recursive method call so it seems likely that the conditions for them are being met from the start (as a new question, I'd suggest).

Comment: Thanks :) I will review everything anyway (before asking more stupidities)

Answer (score 2):

```
function methodOne(someInteger){    
    return methodTwo(someInteger);    
}

function methodTwo(someInteger){    
    if(someInteger == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
    return someInteger*methodTwo(someInteger-1);
    }
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, it does. Thank you a lot! :D Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is definitely coming in two years late! I only hope this will be useful to someone else. Here is my solution:

```
   class Factorial 
   {
   protected $number;

   public function __construct($number)
   {
       $this->number = $number;
   }

   public function getFactorial()
   {
       if ($this->number < 2) {
         return 1;
       }

    else {
        return $this->number * ($this->getFactorial($this->number -=1));
    }
 }

}

$factorial = new Factorial(4);
echo $factorial->getfactorial();
```

You may wrap your logic inside a try catch block to ensure the number entered is indeed an integer.